# Thailand in October - Weather

Tags: thailand, weather-and-climate

I am going to stay in Thailand for 10 Days (5 in Bangkok, 5 in tour) in October (1st to 5th October in Bangkok, 6th to 10th in the locations below), and I would really appreciate a couple of hints on the weather there, since I saw that October is high season for tourists, but it is also still monsoon season.

BANG PA IN – AYUTTHAYA – LOPBURI – PHITSANULOKE – SUKHOTHAI – SI SATCHANALAI – LAMPANG – LAMPHUN – CHIANG MAI – MAE SAI – GOLDEN TRIANGLE – CHIANG RAI

What do I have to expect? How should I dress and what may come in handy?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because weather forecasts and historical weather data are off-topic (and available from other sources).

Comment: @Flimzy This is far from being the first and only historical weather data question we have. Should we close all of them? Want to take this to meta? ;)

Comment: @JoErNanO: Many of them have been closed.  Perhaps a meta discussion is in order.

Comment: Meta question: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3267/444

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters October is not high season, it is shoulder season and not very busy.

The north of Thailand (Lampang and beyond on your itinerary) will be nice for traveling.  Rains have subsided, but may occasionally see light showers.  The first part of your itinerary has a higher chance of rain, but still ok for traveling.

Temperatures will be warm still mostly in the upper 20s and low 30s. You won't likely need cool weather clothes, unless your tour takes you up Doi Inthanon or dinner along a northern river (in Tha Ton to Mae Sai).

Your "tour" section looks awful busy.  You are covering a lot of cities in those 5 days.  You might find it more enjoyable to pick a couple of those cities (like Chiang Mai & Sukhothai) and spend a couple of days in each.

Answer (score 2):

September and October are not exactly the "tourist season" in Thailand, but you can hm still have a great time in there.

I'd be more hesitant to go to beach sides and diving in the southern area in September. The rain will be decreasing by October, so you'll have a better chance of a sunny beach in October.

The temperature is not too cold or not too hot (for the Thai people). About 25°C - 35 ° C.

Chiang Mai/Rai will be a bit sunny/hot in September, so I think it would be better if you go north first and come down south in October.

Generally, you will experience some rains but I don't think it will be too bad. Jan - April are usually quite dry and September is the most rainy.

For the worst, you should probably see Mumbai having 4 ft flood while Karachchi (Pakistan) having a massive hear wave.

Comment: +1, but I think you typoed the temperature range there. 25-35C, perhaps?